# How do I craft a shield in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been messing around with the new Minecraft 1.9 snapshots but there's one thing I can't seem to figure out: how to craft a shield.

I've looked around but I still can't find out how.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Shield

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can craft shields from version 1.9. To craft a shield, you need to use 6 planks of any wood type, and an iron ingot:

[image: Iron ingot top center, wood across middle row, bottom center, top left, and top right]

To give the shield a pattern, you should put the shield and a banner anywhere in the crafting grid together.

Answer (score -4):

You need a recipe for make a [Minecraft shield](https://minecraftworld.website/minecraft-shield/) and you can easily craft a shield..

[image]

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answer posted over 3 years ago.